# Searching for character in an array

Tags: java, search, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d character array that filled with L's and S's with 1 W and 1 H as well. I want to search the array for the W using the following code but I'm getting the wrong position (9,12) as opposed to (7,10).

```java
public static boolean checkForWater(char[][] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
            if (array[i][j] == 'W') {
                System.out.print(i + ", " + j);
                return true;
```

The contents of the array:

[image: the contents of the array]

Comment: Please tag the language / library you use

Answer (score 0):

We have an array with 10 rows and 10 items in every row.
In your example, char 'W' is 10. row 7. Column. Indexes will start from 0, because of that our example will print '9, 6'

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[][] array = {
            {'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'},
            {'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'},
            {'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'},
            {'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'},
            {'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'},
            {'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'},
            {'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'},
            {'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'},
            {'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'},
            {'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'W', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'},
    };
    checkForWater(array);
}

public static boolean checkForWater(char[][] array) {
    for (var row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        for (var column = 0; column < array[row].length; column++) {
            if (array[row][column] == 'W') {
                System.out.println(row + ", " + column); //9, 6
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm using that exact code but it's returning column 12 instead of 6

Comment: Is your input the same? Can you log your input with Arrays.deepToString

Comment: I just checked again and there are spaces in between my letters occupying space in my array I believe